# Mentioning Organization Users in Google Apps Script Card-Based Interface

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-chat

I'm working on a project that involves creating a card-based interface using Google Apps Script. I need to find a way to mention organization users within this interface.

I'd love to hear from anyone who has experience with this or any insights on how to achieve it. If you have any advice, suggestions, or even code examples, please share them!

Thanks in advance.